# Calling a COM+ Component remotely using C#

Tags: .net, com+

I have a little COM+ component as a service on a remote server.

I´m trying to execute a method of this component using:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ComPlusTest.ComTestClass",serverName);

// Create Service
Object service = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Execute Method
String result = service.GetType().InvokeMember("LaunchPackage",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, parameters, null).ToString();
```

The type is returned as null.

What is the best way to do this??

The server is Windows 2003 Enterprise, the service is a .NET component wraped as COM+ (I know that I don´t have to do it that way, but the purpose is to itegrate a legacy App with a .NET component) The purpose of this is just to test that the .NET COM+ Component works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the com object register also on the client side?

Comment: No, the COM object is in other server.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but your approach makes sense.  It looks very similar to the [Interoperating without Proxies](http://codeidol.com/csharp/net-framework/Unmanaged-Interoperability/COM-Interoperability/) but with a remote server.

Perhaps you are running into some other issue (e.g. configuration or permission)?

Some troubleshooting suggestions:

Try to run your test program directly on the "remote" server.

Also, have you tried changing your first line to:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ComPlusTest.ComTestClass",serverName, true);
```

This should throw an exception if an error is encountered and may provide you with some more information on the specific issue you are hitting.

Comment: Thanks, I will add the exception flag to see if I get an exception because right now I´m getting a null.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. The COM+ was not correctly installed on the server. I missed the step of configure the assembly in the .NET Framework Configuration Console.

The steps are:

1. Register the assembly (configure assembly) on .NET Framework Configuration Console
2. Register the assembly in the GAC
3. register the COM+ Application in the Component Services Console. Then Add the Component to the actual assembly(dll)

Jeje, I missed the first one.

How ever I appreciate your time on answering the issue.

Thanks!